# Using condition_variable for waiting recursive_mutex on cross-platform code

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, synchronization, cross-platform

In the example below, I'm trying to allow same-thread recursive lock, but not inter-thread dual locking, by using mutex and condition_variable.

The suitable mutex for this requirement is `std::recursive_mutex`, and the standard
`std::condition_variable` can only except locks from type `std::mutex` so _event is defined as `std::condition_variable_any`.

However, in macOS std library, the symbol `std::condition_variable_any` cannot be found.

> No type named 'condition_variable_any' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'condition_variable'

Is there any way to resolve this in macOS or alternatively use a different native cross-platform std based implementation

```
class x {
...
    std::mutex _guard;
    std::condition_variable_any _event;

    void sync();
};


void x::sync() {
    std::unique_lock<std::recursive_mutex> inputLock(_guard);
    ...
    if(_event.wait_for(inputLock, std::chrono::seconds(120)) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> inputLock2(_guard);
        ...
    }

    //do something... 
}
```

thanks !

Comment: Just to make sure: you have `#include <condition_variable>` in your file, right?

Comment: This was the problem actually, and I thought it's simple not implemented in macOS. Thanks alot. Btw, do you know why do I need to include this special header in macOS and not on other platforms ?

Comment: also interesting to mention, that using the good old `std::conditional_variable` wasn't require any extra header

Comment: Include statements are transitive, and standard library headers are allowed to include any other standard library header. It's possible that one compiler includes this header in something you already use (e.g. in `<mutex>`), but clang doesn't. I'm not sure why would `std::conditional_variable` work, I'd need to dig in the code for that.